# Save changes in CSS after removing Menu from specific page

Tags: css

I am completely new to WordPress and just succeeded in removing the Menu bar from specific sites.
For this purpuse I used

```
.page-id-xxx .site-navigation - primary-navigation{
    display: none;
}
```

However, it always fails to save these changes. Can someone please help out? This might be a stupid question but anyways I cannot find the answer.

Comment: What error you are getting when you try to save?

Comment: Hi Nadine! Where did you put the css code?

Comment: I first clicked the "+" in the source code, then added the mentioned lines (which worked well since the menu disappeared) and then I clicked on Design and Theme Editor (which I had already open when adding the code), scrolled down the page and clicked on "update".

Comment: Try to go to Appearance --> Customizer --> Additional CSS and add your CSS there and save it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I replaced the "." by "#" and added the code in the source code as well as in the "add CSS" section and then it worked!